# What is the limit for the number of streams in one account OpenTok?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I want to create a website that allows users to record and store videos online. I will use OpenTok to record the video. 
If I use one OpenTok account, how many users can record and store their video at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

There is no limit on the number of recordings that you can have per account. If each user is recording themselves and are in a different session, they can record simultaneously without any limit.

However, if you need to record multiple streams in one **session**, you can only record up to **9** simultaneous streams in a Composed Archive. If you need to record more than 9 streams in one session, you can use Individual Archiving to record up to **50** streams at one time per session.

For more information, check out the [OpenTok Archiving Developer Guide](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/).

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.